# what wrong with my regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell, solaris

I have a simple regular expression, and testing egrep on hexadecimal numbers

```
regex="^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*$"
```

when i try to echo any Input it's just print Nothing

```
echo "fe:fe" | egrep $regex
```

The Issue only occur with Solaris Box not with the Linux Box

In Solaris

```
bash-3.2# regex="^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*$"
bash-3.2# echo "fe:fe" | egrep $regex
bash-3.2#
```

Comment: It works to me: `$ echo "fe:fe" | egrep $regex ===>
fe:fe`

Comment: In SOlaris 10 it's doesn't work, In lunux it work

Comment: Will you find enough people to test it under Solaris 10, that's the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no Solaris, but still an old SunOS machine here. The egrep man page here states:

> The /usr/bin/egrep utility accepts full regular  expressions
>        as described on the regexp(5) manual page, except for ... and \{ and \}, ...

So you can not use the repetition, instead try:

```
regex="^([0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])(:[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])*$"
```

Comment: You old SunOS machine is more than likely running Solaris. Have a look to `/etc/release`.

Comment: @jlliagre: you are right its using Solaris (but not 10, just 9)

Answer (score 2):

Use `/usr/xpg4/bin/egrep` instead of `/usr/bin/egrep`. The former is POSIX compliant and supports full regular expressions.